# Google OAuth 2.0 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js, render

I am developing a Node.js application and have implemented Google OAuth 2.0 using `PassportJS` google strategy. and I enabled Google People API .The production build is running on Render. When I try to sign in with localhost during development, it works perfectly fine and successfully logs me in and redirects me. However, when I attempt to sign in with the hosting domain, Google OAuth gives me an `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`.

I have added the `Authorized JavaScript origins` for the production domain, making sure it matches the localhost entry. I have also added the same entry as the `Authorized redirect URIs` in the Cloud Console. Despite these configurations, I receive the error message `You can't sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this issue. Error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch.` Any help!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/unl4X.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KytXt.jpg)

I tried to do some mutation on the redirect URL, adding a slash. and use another separate credential for the production domain but it did not work.
"I have attached two pics showcasing the error and my configurations"